# SUM expression with column and row scope

Tags: reporting-services

I work in lending and we are trying to get the percentages of purchases and refis to show for the months. The problem that I am having is that I cannot get the scope correct.

Here is the current list

[image: Here is the current list]

Andhere are the row groups

[image: And here are the row groups]

I know this is definitely a scope issue - I just can't figure out a way to have it take into account the month and the year. I have had success with it doing the percent of the year value. I am trying to simply show the percent of purchases and Refis for a given month for a given year.

For example, If we have 60 purchases and 40 Refinances for January of 2019 - I want it to show 60% and 40%.

I have tried messing around with the row and columns groups every which way and I still cannot seem to figure it out. Any help would be largely appreciated.

```
= SUM(Fields!TOTALLOANAMT.Value, "Grouped_Loan_Purpose5") /
  SUM(Fields!TOTALLOANAMT.Value, "App_Sent_Year1")
```

Comment: That doesn't look like DAX to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fairly simple solution that you could use to avoid any headache involved with grouping.  I would suggest simply using the values in the textboxes to calculate your percentages.  You can just do something like the following.

```
=(ReportItems!PurchasesTextbox.Value / ReportItems!TotalTextbox.Value) * 100

=(ReportItems!RefinanceTextbox.Value / ReportItems!TotalTextbox.Value) * 100
```

Then you can just format as percentages and leave everything else alone.